# How To Dynamically Create a Param Name that Contains Array Syntax

Tags: grails

In one place in my system I do the following, which works correctly:

```
   log.debug params."${tagType}"_${i}" //resolves to, e.g : params.title_0
```

Furthermore, the following also works:

```
log.debug params."${'setTagtypesList[0].tagtype.id'} // hard coded 0 index
```

(Note that above resolves to `params.'setTagtypesList[0].tagtype.id'` and that the single quotes are necessary.)

However the params request that follows results in NULL:

```
def someInt = 0
log.debug params."'setTagtypesList[someInt].tagtype.id'" //dynamic index
```

So how can I dynamically create a param name that contains array syntax? I'm using Grails 1.3.9.

Comment: Here's where I got messed up originally: I started with "${params.setTagtypesList[0].tagtype.id}" which doesn't work. But I found that "${params.'setTagtypesList[0].tagtype.id'}" does work. So I got messed up thinking I needed the single quotes. But in the end the issue was that I needed was params."${...}".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve what you want, including:

```
params."setTagtypesList[${someInt}].tagtype.id"
params['setTagtypesList[' + someInt + '].tagtype.id']
```

Both of which are ultimately shorthand for

```
params.get('setTagtypesList[' + someInt + '].tagtype.id')
```

The thing to remember with GStrings is that anything inside `${}` is a Groovy expression, anything outside the braces is taken literally.

However note that

```
params["setTagtypesList[${someInt}].tagtype.id"]
```

Would likely *not* work, because it is looking up a map entry with a GString key rather than a String. The property access dot notation does an implicit `toString()` on the key before looking it up, this is one of the cases where you do need to be aware of the difference between Strings and GStrings.